# Bash regexp for all positive real numbers (excluding 0)

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Following regexp accepts all positive real numbers (excluding 0)

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$
```

It works e.g. in JavaScript.
What's the correct way in bash to test with operator =~, is some variable consistent with the regexp (e.g. with characters must be escaped with backslash).

Bash version is 4.4.12.

Comment: your regex doesn't work even in javascript: `0.05`, `0.1`, `.2` don't match

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul they do, did you try?

Comment: my bad i didn't double the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
if [[ $v =~ ^([0-9]+|([0-9]*[.][0-9]+))$ ]] && ! [[ $v =~ ^(0*(\.0+))$ ]]; then 
    echo "Match"
fi
```